# Proof verification: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $S \subset T \subset A$, then $f(S) \subset f(T)$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

*Proof*. If $S\subset T$, then for all $s\in S$ there exists $t \in T$ such that $f(s)=f(t)$.

In other words, for all $s\in S$ there exists $b \in f(T)$ such that $f(s)=b$.

Therefore, all $f(s)$ is contained in $f(T)$ and thus $f(S)\subset f(T)$. (QED?)

---

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not..

You should take an arbitrary $y\in f(S)$, then there is $x\in S$ such that $f(x)=y$. But since $x\in T$ we have also $y\in f(T)$, so $f(S)\subseteq f(T)$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Though, could you point out the fault(s) in my proof? EDT. Was it the previous mistake (I have corrected it) that I wrote $\in$ instead of $\subset$ when writing $f(S) \subset f(T)$?

Comment: For example, I do not understand what you wanted to say with the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, that was also a mistake

Comment: Okey, I've got it now..